# code says run time error 424 what is wrong

Tags: excel, vba

when the I run this, it pops up with the run error 424 when I says debug it highlights the setsourceWS. I want to grab multiple tabs from the excel file and save it to a new workbook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Copysheetandsave()
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, savePath As String

Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("400", "410", "420", "430", "450", "490", "491", "499", "425", "442")).Copy

    savePath = "C:\Users\"

    sourceWs.Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=savePath & "name YTD.xlsx"
         .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `.Copy` at the end of that line that errors.

Comment: You also can't declare it as a Worksheet and then assign multiple sheets to it.

Comment: removed copy didn't work.?  what do I need to put instead?

Comment: Additionally, replace `As Worksheet` with `As Sheets`. BTW, 1.) if one of the worksheets doesn't exist: `RTE 9`, 2.) if all exist: `RTE 424`, 3.) when `.Copy` is removed: `RTE 13`, 4.) when `As Sheets` is used: no error.

Answer (score 0):

### Export Sheets From a List

```vb
Sub ExportSheets()
    
    Const SAVE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\"
    Const SAVE_NAME As String = "name YTD.xlsx"
    Dim SheetNames() As Variant: SheetNames = Array( _
       "400", "410", "420", "430", "450", "490", "491", "499", "425", "442")
    
    Dim sshs As Sheets: Set sshs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNames)
    
    sshs.Copy
    
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        .SaveAs SAVE_PATH & SAVE_NAME, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```